# MySQL field structure

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table data type integer field. the value is stored as 1, 2, 3 .., 10000.

I want to format it with starting from 00001, 00002, 0003 etc., (the whole number to be 5 digit).

Is there any function to do?

or how do i set it manually in phpMyAdmin..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change the column type to INT(5) ZEROFILL. From the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html):

> When used in conjunction with the optional extension attribute ZEROFILL, the default padding of spaces is replaced with zeros. For example, for a column declared as INT(5) ZEROFILL, a value of 4 is retrieved as 00004.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE table1(x INT(5) ZEROFILL);
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES(4);
SELECT * FROM table1;
```

Result:

```
00004
```

Comment: how can i add ZEROFILL in editing the table structure? i got only Field, Type, Length/Values, Default, Collation, Attributes, Null, AUTO_INCREMENT, Comments, MIME type, Browser transformation, Transformation options.. where can i set the ZEROFILL value?

Comment: Set the attributes to UNSIGNED ZEROFILL.